# How does 'endOnTick' work in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

[In this Highcharts chart](http://plnkr.co/edit/VRUJsM0RGA5ZA6T1Z7CU?p=preview) I have a line with data points that end in point 5, but the `xAxis` ends in point 6 even though there is no data in that point. This is because I set `endOnTick:true`, question is what is the logic behind `endOnTick`? why is it adding a new point and doesn't end with the data?

Javascript

```
   var settings =  
        {
         "chart": {
           "type":"line"
        },
       "xAxis": { 
          "endOnTick":true
       },
       "series":[
           {"name":"series1","data":[[1,1200],[2,2200],[3,3200],[4,1800],[5,1500]]},
           {"name":"series2","data":[[1,1050],[2,2050],[3,1650],[4,1450],[5,1350]]},
           {"name":"series3","data":[[1,1250],[2,2250],[3,1850],[4,1650],[5,1550]]}]
       }


    $('#container').highcharts(settings);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is pretty much what you would expect. If `endOnTick` is `true`, it will extend the axis to make sure it stops on a tick. However, it is not very visible in your example.

If you look closely at the x-axis you can see that if you have `endOnTick: false` the axis goes very slightly beyond 5. This is because of `maxPadding` defaulting to `0.01` for the x-axis. This very slight extension beyond 5 means that setting `endOnTick: true` has to extend the axis to the next tick.

You can test this by [setting `maxPadding: 0` and `endOnTick: true`](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFd4F9Sbn1WG2hMW0ZH6?p=preview). Then you see that as the axis does not go beyond 5, it does not generate the extra point.

Note that these settings have differing defaults for the x-axis and the y-axis.